# How to set options timeout in resolv.conf in docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, resolv.conf

How (if any) it is possible to add `options timeout` to `/etc/resolv.conf` in docker container running in Kubernetes cluster?

The file is generated, so it's not possible to do that in `Dockerfile`. On the other way, it's owned by root, so it's not possible to do that in shell script by starting container either.

I guess it belongs to cluster configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: nginx
    dnsConfig:
      options:
      - name: timeout
        value: "2"
```

Read more on this in [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config)